# JavaScript removing list elements by class name

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I am having an issue with my javascript function in regards to removing elements. What I have below is two lists inside a div menu with each `<li>` marked by a class according to the category of drink and the drinks themselves. I also have a button that opens a modal box where the user would type in a drink category to remove. I decided to approach this by naming `<li>` with classes by the drink category and then taking a js function to get the elements by class name from the input text node and to remove those elements with what the user typed.

```
<div class = "menu">
<ul>
  <li class = "coffee"><a href="#">french press</a></li>
  <li class = "tea"><a href="#">english breakfast/a></li>
  <li class = "milk"><a href="#">whole</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class = "coffee"><a href="#">dark roast</a></li>
  <li class = "tea"><a href="#">green tea</a></li>
  <li class = "milk"><a href="#">two percent</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<button type="button" id ="openmodal">Click Me!</button>

 <div id="myDeleteModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h1 class="modal-title">
                <b>Type the drink category you want to remove </b>
            </h1>

            <input id="deletedrinktext" type="text" />
            <button id="delete">Remove</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-defaultdeletedrink" id="closedbtn" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="">Close</button>



        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
        var modal = document.getElementById("myDeleteModal");

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("openmodal");
        var closebtn = document.getElementById("closedbtn");


        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
        btn.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        closebtn.onclick = function (event) {

            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
</script>
```

```
<script>
        (function () {
            document.querySelector('#delete').addEventListener('click', function () {
                let inputRemover = document.querySelector('#deletedrinktext');
                let itemRemover = document.createTextNode(inputRemover.value); 
                let listRemover = document.getElementsByClassName(itemRemover);
               
                    for (var i = 0; i < listRemover.length; i++) {
                        if (document.contains(listRemover)) {
                            listRemover[i].remove();
                        }
                    }


                


                inputRemover.value = ""; // clear input
            });
        })();
    </script>
```

So what I want to replicate is a user would open the modal box, type in coffee and click remove. This would remove from the document the following two elements:

```
<li class = "coffee"><a href="#">french press</a></li>
<li class = "coffee"><a href="#">dark roast</a></li>
```

This function isn't working so far and I am not sure if there is an error in my JS in getting each element or if going with the class approach is not the way to go about it? When I type in the name of the category just like written in my HTML, the element in the list still displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remove()` is not a function of `Array` in javascript. I think your best approach would be to just not display the elements you want to remove. To do just change your handler function to this:

```
let inputRemover = document.querySelector('#deletedrinktext');
let listRemover = document.getElementsByClassName(inputRemover.value);

for (let i = 0; i < listRemover.length; i++) {
  if (document.contains(listRemover[i])) {
    listRemover[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wc8zxpk0/) to try it out without modal functionality.

This also helps you if you maybe want to reset the list. To do so, just set the display property on every element to block.

Also, I don't knwo if it is a copy paste issue but the `a` at english breakfast is missing a `<` in the closing tag.